# Setting an environment variable to another environment variable inside of a supervisor script

Tags: environment-variables, supervisord

I am trying to set an environment variable to another environment variable inside of supervisor.  Here is an example:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
loglevel = debug

[program:nodejs]
redirect_stderr = true
environment=REDIS_URL=$REDIS_PORT
directory = /usr/src/myapp/
command = node /usr/src/myapp/app.js
autostart = true
autorestart = true
```

I can set the env to a string, and everything works.  Is there any way to set the env var to another env var?  Thanks.

Comment: I have been able to do this by removing the 'environment' modifying the 'command' as follows:

command = /bin/bash -c 'export REDIS_URL=$REDIS_PORT && node /usr/src/iodocs/app.js'

But that seems pretty hacky

Comment: Why is this tagged `nodejs`? Are you speaking of the environment variables for nodejs or a simple bash script?

Comment: Probably shouldn't be - thought that there may be a way to call node with env vars.  I will remove.

Answer (score 2):

While this is not the optimal solution, I basically rolled this into a bash shell as follows:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:nodejs]
user = www-data
directory = /usr/src/iodocs/
command = /bin/bash -c 'export REDIS_URL=$REDIS_PORT && node app.js'
autostart = true
autorestart = true
```

Works, but not pretty